# comparing two tables with identical columns using T-SQL in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

Scenario: need to compare two different tables with identical columns and need to load the different records into a new table with date and table name from which they are loaded. Data is loaded again into one of the initial tables and are compared again for the different records. This time the records which are different are need to be loaded into the table which is created along with column names that are changed when compared to last loaded data.

I was able to query the different record into the created table with table name and date but unable get the column names that are changed when compared to old record.Could you please help me with this issue?

```
INSERT INTO compare_tables 
   SELECT
       MIN(TableName), CUSTNMBR, CUSTCLAS, PRCLEVEL, INACTIVE,
       GETDATE() AS load_Date, 
       ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, CITY, STATE, ZIP 
   FROM 
      ((SELECT 
            'Table1' AS TableName, CUSTNMBR, CUSTCLAS, PRCLEVEL, INACTIVE, 
            GETDATE() AS load_Date,
            ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, CITY, STATE, ZIP 
        FROM table1) 
       UNION ALL
       (SELECT
            'Table2' AS TableName, CUSTNMBR, CUSTCLAS, PRCLEVEL, INACTIVE,  
            GETDATE() AS load_Date,
            ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, CITY, STATE, ZIP 
        FROM Table2)) AS I 
   GROUP BY 
       CUSTNMBR, CUSTCLAS, PRCLEVEL, INACTIVE, PRESENT_Date, 
       ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, CITY‌​, STATE, ZIP 
   HAVING 
       COUNT(1) = 1
```

Comment: INSERT INTO compare_tables
Select  MIN(TableName),CUSTNMBR,CUSTCLAS,PRCLEVEL,INACTIVE,GETDATE() AS load_Date,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,ADDRESS3,CITY,STATE,ZIP from
(
(Select      'Table1' AS TableName,CUSTNMBR,CUSTCLAS,PRCLEVEL,INACTIVE,GETDATE() AS load_Date,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,ADDRESS3,CITY,STATE,ZIP from  table1)
union all 
(Select       'Table2' AS TableName, CUSTNMBR,CUSTCLAS,PRCLEVEL,INACTIVE,GETDATE() AS load_Date,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,ADDRESS3,CITY,STATE,ZIP  from Table2)
) AS I GROUP BY  CUSTNMBR,CUSTCLAS,PRCLEVEL,INACTIVE,PRESENT_Date,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,ADDRESS3,CITY,STATE,ZIP  HAVING COUNT(1)=1

Comment: I used this query to get the different records by creating compare_tables table.